# Going from Characteristics to Parametric Solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

This is what I have so far:

$$u_t + 2tu_x = x$$

$$u(x,0) = 1 + x^2, 1 < x< 3$$

The PDE is $(2t, 1, x)$ $\cdot$ $(u_t, u_x, -1)$ = $0$

We get characteristics by solving:

$$\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial r} = 2t$$

$$\dfrac{\partial t}{\partial r}=1$$

$$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial r}=x$$

I know the parametric solution is defined with the initial conditions $x(0) = s$ where $1<x<3$, $t(0)=0$, $u(0)=1+s^2$ (this is an example) but I don't know how to make the jump from the partial derivatives to the parametrized equations.
Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Note that if $u = u(x(t), t)$ then by the chain rule we have $$\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$$ and equating this with your PDE gives \begin{align}
(1) \quad \frac{dx}{dt} &= 2t \\
(2) \quad \frac{du}{dt} &= x
\end{align}
(note this is the same as eliminating $dr$ in your system of equations as $dt = dr$). Solving $(1)$ gives $x = t^{2} + x_{0}$, substituting this into $(2)$ and solving gives $u = t^{3}/3 + x_{0} t + f(x_{0}) = xt - 2t^{3}/3 + f(x-t^{2})$. Now apply your initial condition carefully.

Answer (score 0):

$$u_t+2tu_x=x$$
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{2t}=\frac{du}{x}$$
First characteristic : $\quad \frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{2t} \quad\to\quad x-t^2=c_1$

Second characteristic : $\quad \frac{dt}{1}=\frac{du}{c_1+t^2}\quad\to\quad u-c_1t-\frac{1}{3}t^3=c_2$

General solution of the PDE : $\quad u-(x-t^2)t-\frac{1}{3}t^3=F(x-t^2)$
$$u(x,t)=xt-\frac{2}{3}t^3+F(x-t^2) \tag 1$$

$u(x,0)=x=F(x)\quad$ determines the function $F(X)=X$.

Putting it into Eq.$(1)$ with $F(x-t^2)=(x-t^2)$ gives :
$$u(x,t)=xt-\frac{2}{3}t^3+(x-t^2)$$